# Python Playwright downloads a file with incorrect extension

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

Playwright successfully find the download button, clicks on it, and then instead of the csv file I get some sort of a windows ID.

[This is what I get when the download button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPXz8.png)

This is the code that I tried:

```
with page.expect_download() as download_info:
    page.get_by_role("button", name="CSV").click()

download = download_info.value
download.save_as(path_downloads + '\\Input Currency Rates.csv')
```

Comment: You might have 2 buttons (or more) with the same name. Please show us the HTML page with these buttons.